# custom http request header in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I have a rest api made using philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver.I have set the authentication
api key for the rest api.So that all request will be authenticated usingthe api key.

The request parameter for apikey is X-API-KEY and the key should be sent as request parameter in the header.
But I cant get itworking using curl.But in rest console and post man,I can properly set the request parameter in the header.But i cant do it with curl.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'www.exampleapi.come',
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'martinbean:4eefab4111b2a',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => 'X-API-KEY:123456789'
));
$response = curl_exec($ch) ;
echo $response ;
?>
```

I have tried this,but itsnot working,its showing invalid api key

[image: this way its working]

How to do this part using curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php curl wrapper documentation says that you need to pass an array to this option.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

So this may work :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'www.exampleapi.come',
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'martinbean:4eefab4111b2a',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-API-KEY:123456789')
));
$response = curl_exec($ch) ;
echo $response ;
?>
```